# xcodebuild build-for-testing vs build actions

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

Since Xcode 8.x Apple has added `build-for-testing` action argument, however, it is unclear to me whether if I want to publish the resulting artifacts after I used `build-for-testing`, do I need to re-run xcodebuild with the `build` action argument?

Can anyone answer whether `build-for-testing` forces `debug` configuration or disables certain optimizations?

Answer (score 4):

**Exploring new `xcodebuild`**

`xcodebuild` is the command line tool to build, run and execute our application from command line.

This is used in the Xcode server. Xcode 8 now has some improvements in the `xcodebuild` command line tools.

```
Build For Testing
```

The xcodebuild now has `build-for-testing` option, it takes workspace scheme and destination as usual but on top of that it will create `XCTESTRUN` file.

This should build our app for the testing and create `xctestrun`
file.

It is more useful for BDD and Continuous Integration.

Comment: So, given a continuous integration server, would you use 'build-for-testing' in order to: test + deploy artifacts? or would you use 'build' for artifacts and 'build-for-testing' only for testing?

Comment: Actually I use the archive command. No need to build for testing or artifacts. I archive and export, so that I can deploy for release or test in TestFlight via iTunesConnect.

Comment: And assuming your deliverable is not an .ipa but a .framework?

Answer (score 3):

`build-for-testing` is not for distribution of your app to testers but instead to run unit tests using it. This build has special compile options that make it testable. Basically, it shouldn't be used for anything else except for running unit tests on it.

Comment: Can you share a link to where this is clearly documented?

Comment: @rob this is the same as executing `Product` -> `Build For` -> `Testing` in the Xcode which is similar to executing `Product` -> `Test` except tests are not executed. I don't have a link to share but basically building for Running/Testing/Profiling implies that this is a special build mode for a concrete purpose.

Comment: Ok, I was looking for a more definitive explanation of the special compile options, rather than making assumptions about the behavior, because the man page for `xcodebuild` does not mention them. The man page also documents `test-without-building`, but doesn't indicate you have to run `build-for-testing` first.